# Chrome mobile debugging over usb, no console.log

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome when inspecting a web page from a mobile device connected via USB, the javascript console does not print console.log statements.  It also doesn't respond to alerts.  It doesn't seem to support any interaction at the command line, such as setting variables.  Is there something I need to do to get the console to behave normally, as if I was debugging Chrome for desktop?

Comment: Check: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out immediately.  I had turned off Javascript on the mobile browser and forgot to turn it back on.